# Why is this javascript object referring to a previous object's properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object

I am creating a class that can create any number of captchas on a page.I have a `captcha` class that I am using to instantiate new captcha objects `c1` and `c2`. Here is my JS:

```
 $(function(){
    var captcha = {
        parentForm : '',
        container : '',
        captcha_input : '',
        number1 : 0,
        number2 : 0,

        createCaptcha : function(form_ID){
            var newHtml;
            this.parentForm = $('#' + form_ID);
            this.container = this.parentForm.find('.captchaContainer');
            this.number1 = this.randomNumber(10);
            this.number2 = this.randomNumber(10);


            newHtml = 'What does ' + this.number1 + ' plus ' + this.number2 + ' equal? <b class="required goldenrod" title="Required Field">*</b><br/><br/><input type="text" name="captcha">';
            this.container.html(newHtml);
        },

        isValid : function(){
            console.log(this.container);
            this.captcha_input = this.container.find('input[name="captcha"]');
            if (this.number1 + this.number2 == this.captcha_input.val()) {
                this.captcha_input.css('background-color', '')
                return true;
            } else{
                this.captcha_input.css('background-color', '#FFCCCC')
                alert(this.number1 + ' plus ' + this.number2 + ' does not equal ' + this.captcha_input.val() + '. Please try again.');
                this.captcha_input.focus();
                return false;
            }
        },

        randomNumber : function(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1)); }
    }


    var c1 = captcha,
        c2 = captcha;

    c1.createCaptcha("form1");
    c2.createCaptcha("form2");

    $('#form1 input[type="submit"]').click(function() { 
        if(c1.isValid()){
            alert('Captcha is valid!');
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#form2 input[type="submit"]').click(function() { 
        if(c2.isValid()){
            alert('Captcha is valid!');
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });


});
```

And my HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
    <div class="captchaContainer"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <div class="captchaContainer"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I click on `form1`'s submit button, it seems like the `isValid` method is being ran for `c2` and not `c1` like I expect. Any idea why this is doing so?

A few things to note:

- If I add more `captcha` instances and HTML, each submit button will run `isValid` on the last instance of `captcha` on click.
- This needs to work for IE8+

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/GBp9r/) of the code in action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: c1 and c2 are both references to the same `captcha` object.

Comment: @RickViscomi agreed, since the code states var c1 = captcha, c2 = captcha; both c1 and c2 are pointers to the captcha object and thereby they both are the same object this causes changes to 1 object c1 to affect c2 and the catcha object.

Comment: Ah that all makes sense. Thanks! I guess I was under the impression that defining those variables would make an instance rather than a pointer. Can either of you let me know why this is so with objects stored in variable and not with something such as numbers stored in variables? `var myNumber = 1, myNewNumber = myNumber;` **vs** `var myObject = {prop1:'red'}, myNewObject = myObject;`

Comment: @Fillip: It works the same for all data types! The difference is that in case of objects, the value of the variable is rather a reference to the object, instead the object itself. Also, objects are mutable, while numbers are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @plalx had a valid answer, it wasn't an ideal answer for my scenario. Since I cannot instantiate a class that was created from an object literal (without use of `Object.create`), I decided to refactor my class with a function instead:

```
$(function(){
    var Captcha = function(){
        var parentForm = '',
            container = '',
            captcha_input = '',
            number1 = 0,
            number2 = 0,

            createCaptcha = function(form_ID){
                var newHtml;
                this.parentForm = $('#' + form_ID);
                this.container = this.parentForm.find('.captchaContainer');
                this.number1 = randomNumber(10);
                this.number2 = randomNumber(10);


                newHtml = 'What does ' + this.number1 + ' plus ' + this.number2 + ' equal? <b class="required goldenrod" title="Required Field">*</b><br/><br/><input type="text" name="captcha">';
                this.container.html(newHtml);
            },

            isValid = function(){
                this.captcha_input = this.container.find('input[name="captcha"]');
                if (this.number1 + this.number2 == this.captcha_input.val()) {
                    this.captcha_input.css('background-color', '')
                    return true;
                } else{
                    this.captcha_input.css('background-color', '#FFCCCC')
                    alert(this.number1 + ' plus ' + this.number2 + ' does not equal ' + this.captcha_input.val() + '. Please try again.');
                    this.captcha_input.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            },

            randomNumber = function(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1)); }

            return{
                createCaptcha : createCaptcha,
                isValid : isValid
            }
    }


    // Instantiation of Captcha objects
    var c1 = new Captcha,
        c2 = new Captcha;

    c1.createCaptcha("form1");
    c2.createCaptcha("form2");

    $('#form1 input[type="submit"]').click(function() { if(c1.isValid()){ alert('Captcha is valid!'); }else{ return false; } });
    $('#form2 input[type="submit"]').click(function() { if(c2.isValid()){ alert('Captcha is valid!'); }else{ return false; } });

});
```

Here is the new working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/3wh4e/)

TLDR: Since object literals cannot be instantiated without `Object.create`, I used a function to create the class instead, and then instantiated like so:

```
var c1 = new Captcha,
    c2 = new Captcha;
```

Comment: `var c1 = $.extend({}, captcha)`, etc. would have worked also.

Comment: Interesting. Not a bad solution either,

Answer (score 1):

`c1` and `c2` are both the same object. Use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create different instances. `Object.create` is not supported in old browsers, however there's a polyfill in the link I provided.

```
var c1 = Object.create(captcha),
    c2 = Object.create(captcha);
```

Comment: Looks like this will do the trick for me. I guess I just misunderstood how to instantiate a class made from an object literal. Before I accept this answer, do you know if there are any cross browser issues with `Object.create`?

Comment: @FillipPeyton Yes, use [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) to support incompatible browsers.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Thanks for that. While this polyfill would fix my issue, I don't necessarily want to add more code when I can just restructure my class to be created from a function rather than an object literal. If you want to submit an answer that suggests using a function instead, I would gladly accept that answer. Thanks!

Comment: @FillipPeyton Thanks, but I probably won't be adding another answer. And if you decide to reconsider, that polyfill is quite simple, and Object.create is part of the current language standard (it's just not supported by older browsers like IE8 and below).

Comment: @bfavaretto - Fair enough. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform a deep copy of the object.

```
 function deepCopy(obj) { 
     var res = {};
     for (var key in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             res[key] = obj[key];
         };
     }
     res.prototype = obj.prototype; // this would make it a deep copy.
     return res;
};
var c1 = deepCopy(captcha);
```

Comment: Interesting. Never knew about that. Thanks @alex23!